# Error when creating script: QgsExpressionContextUtils not defined

Tags: error, pyqgis-3

This is the piece of code that is failing:

```
##nomenclatura = string '1.1.E.3.52'
##pdfOutput = output string
from qgis.core import QgsProject
project = QgsProject.instance()
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(project,'Manzana_actual',nomenclatura)
tx = pScope.variable('Manzana_actual')
layer = project.instance().mapLayersByName('Mzs,Qt,Chs')[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
#continues#
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(project,'Manzana_actual',nomenclatura)
>
> NameError: name 'QgsExpressionContextUtils' is not defined

I copy pasted all the code in the python console and it works, but fails when I try to save it as a script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `QgsExpressionContextUtils` as it is part of `qgis.core`. So you can include it in your imports:

```
from qgis.core import QgsExpressionContextUtils, QgsProject
```

---

Most modules are loaded for you to use in the Python Console. But when using scripts, you will need to manually load the modules yourself which would explain the error you received.